# I receive the following error when I want to re-register a form: NoMethodError (undefined method `permit' for "create":String)

Tags: ruby-on-rails

when I send the form data i receive:

NoMethodError (undefined method `permit' for "create":String):

app/controllers/actions_controller.rb:53:in `action_params'
app/controllers/actions_controller.rb:18:in`create'

This is the form:

```
= controlled_form do
  = render 'shared/error_messages', object: @action
  = remote_form(@action, html: { id: "actionsForm" }) do |f|
    = input_group "fas fa-file-alt" do
      = f.text_field :name, \
        autofocus: true, \
        placeholder: t('actions.form.name'), \
        class: "form-control"

    = input_group 'fas fa-file-alt' do
      = f.text_area :description, \
        placeholder: t('actions.form.description'), \
        class: "form-control"
```

and the function of creating:

```
def create
    @action = Action.new(action_params)
    if @action.save
        flash[:success] = "\"#{@action.name}\" was created"
        respond_to do |format|
        format.js { render js: "Turbolinks.visit('#{actions_path}')" }
    end
    else
        render_form status: :bad_request
    end
end
```

finally:

```
def action_params
    params.require(:action).permit(:name, :description)
end
```

Comment: what are the params getting sent on submission?  Can you share those?

Answer (score 1):

"action" is an special key on the params hash that references the current controller's action, you shouldn't use `action` as a paremeter. I'm not sure what are you using for your forms (`remote_form` is not a common rails form helper method), but it should give you an option to change that like the `scope` option on the `form_with` helper https://apidock.com/rails/ActionView/Helpers/FormHelper/form_with

Change it to something like "action_object" or anything other than "action" and then do the same change at `action_params`.